# line equation for lane lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

i have to find the mid points of each lane in a binary iamge , i wrote a code but that is too long and its give error when ever i change the pic of road . i have to save the mid points of each lane and then by finding slope and intercept i have to draw  lines on that binary image. 
 here is the code

```
    x=imread('C:\users\guest\documents\matlab\1.png');
    [q,r]= size(x);
    n4=zeros(q,r);
    midpoint= zeros (720,2); % Array to store midlle points of road lane.

    % finding mid points of both lanes.
     for n3=540:720
       s=x(n3,:);
       startIndex =1;                                                                                    
       lastIndex =1280;                                                                                 
       pixelsRow =s;  
       FirstWhiteStart=0; FirstWhiteEnd=0; SecondWhiteStart=0; SecondWhiteEnd=0;

       for k=1:1280
            if (pixelsRow(k) == 1)&&(FirstWhiteStart == 0)                                         
            FirstWhiteStart =k;
            elseif (pixelsRow(k)==0)&&(FirstWhiteStart>0)&&(FirstWhiteEnd==0)             
            FirstWhiteEnd=k-1;
            elseif (pixelsRow(k)== 1)&&(FirstWhiteEnd>0)&&(SecondWhiteStart==0)
            SecondWhiteStart=k;
            elseif (pixelsRow(k)==0)&&(SecondWhiteStart>0)&&(SecondWhiteEnd==0)          
            SecondWhiteEnd=k-1;
            end
            end
            m1=(FirstWhiteStart + FirstWhiteEnd)./2;  % first lanes middle point
            m1r = round(m1);
            if (m1r <= 1)

             mp= sub2ind(size(midpoint),n3,1);
             midpoint(mp) = 0;

              elseif (m1r > 1)
              indices = sub2ind(size(n4),n3,m1r);
              n4(indices) = 1;
              if (m1r >=640)
              mp= sub2ind(size(midpoint),n3,2);
              midpoint(mp) =  m1r;
              elseif (m1r <= 640)
              mp= sub2ind(size(midpoint),n3,1);
              midpoint(mp) = m1r;
              end 
          end  

          m2=(SecondWhiteStart + SecondWhiteEnd+1)./2;  % second lane middle point.
          m2r = round(m2);

           if (m2r <= 1)
            indices = sub2ind(size(n4),n3,m2r);
           n4(indices) = 0;
           mp= sub2ind(size(midpoint),n3,1);
           midpoint(mp) = 0;


            elseif (m2r > 1)
            indices = sub2ind(size(n4),n3,m2r);
            n4(indices) = 1;
            if (m2r >=640)
            mp= sub2ind(size(midpoint),n3,2);
            midpoint(mp) =  m2r;
            elseif (m2r <=640)
            mp= sub2ind(size(midpoint),n3,1);
            midpoint(mp) =  m2r;
            end 
              end
              end

           pairpoints = nchoosek([540:720],2);

           var1 = zeros (16290,2);                        % array to store variables a and b of first lane. 
           var2 = zeros (16290,2);                        % array to stote variables a and b of second lane.

          % calling middle points previously stored in array,putting in equation.
           for n = 1 : 16290

            x1 = pairpoints(n,1);                           %value of frst row
            x2 = pairpoints(n,2);                           %value of 2nd row 
            y1 = midpoint (pairpoints(n,1), 1);             %rows of midpoint matrix are                   specified from pairpoints location martix
            y2 = midpoint (pairpoints(n,2), 1);
            z1 = midpoint (pairpoints(n,1), 2);
            z2 = midpoint (pairpoints(n,2), 2);

            a1 = (y2 - y1) ./ (x2 - x1);
            a2 = (z2 - z1) ./ (x2 - x1);


             b1=(((x2)*(y1)) - (x1)*(y2)) ./ (x2 - x1);
             b2=(((x2)*(z1)) - (x1)*(z2)) ./ (x2 - x1);

                  % variables a and b of first lane.
             line = sub2ind(size(var1),n,1);
             var1(line) = a1;
                line = sub2ind(size(var1),n,2);
                  var1(line) = b1;

              % variables A and b of second lane.
             line = sub2ind(size(var2),n,1);
             var2(line) = a2;
              line = sub2ind(size(var2),n,2);
              var2(line) = b2;

              end

              v11=round(var1);
              v22=round(var2);

              % eleminating zeros from array. 
             [i,j] = find(v11);

             a1 = v11(i,1);
             a1= a1(a1~=0);
             b1 = v11(i,2);
             b1= b1(b1~=0);

             a11=median(a1)
             b11=median(b1)

            % eleminating zeros from array. 
            [k,l] = find(v22);

             row = i;
             a2 = v22(k,1);
             a2= a2(a2~=0);
             b2 = v22(k,2);
             b2= b2(b2~=0);

              a22=median(a2)
              b22=median(b2)

                %assign variables
             lin=zeros(720,2);

              % implementation of final line equation.
            for x1 = 1:720   

            % equation becomes (w = eh + f) as actual was (y = ax + b)
           y1 = (a11 * x1) + b11;
           y2 = (a22 * x1) + b22;


           col = sub2ind( size(lin),x1,1);         % equation for first lane.
           lin(col)= y1;

           col = sub2ind( size(lin),x1,2);         % equation for second lane.
          lin(col)= y2;

            end

          array=lin;

          r= 1:720;
          c= 1:1280;
           x(r,c)= 0;
          imshow(x);
         imwrite(x,'a.png');

          image =imread('C:\users\guest\documents\matlab\a.png');

         for r1 = 1:720
            for  c = 1:2;
                 if array(r1,c) < 0;
                  lin(r1,c) = abs (array(r1,c));
                   image(r1,lin(r1,c))= 0;

                 elseif array(r1,c) > 0;
                    image(r1,lin(r1,c))= 1;

                 end
            end
        end
        imshow(image)
```

Comment: one of my fellow said i have to solve that with help of houghline but thats not working.

Comment: You've dumped a lot of code, nobody is going to debug that for you. To debug it yourself, you need to start by looking at which images it does and doesn't work for and why. In particular, look at what assumptions your code makes. Why `for n3=540:720`? (what's special about that range? does it hold for all images?).

Comment: yes it hold for all images , because lane lines are at lower portion, so mostly we only take lower half or less than lower half, image size is 720*1280 . we slect lower part from 540 to 720, i ll show u the pic on which we working